# Slowly expanding text

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make expanding text in CSS. What I need is a part of hyperlink to show when you hover on it. What I have is this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5cwLLud/)** but there's a line height issue with that particular font.

I also cannot get rid of `line-height` and for some reason transition on width doesn't work. Any solution to my problem or any other approach to get the desired effect is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use css transition with `auto`. If you need a CSS only solution, you will need a fixed value:  [JS Fiddle - fixed width](http://jsfiddle.net/y5cwLLud/1/)

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0.25s linear;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a:hover span {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a max-width and transition that. This way, it will still allow for dynamic content. However, depending on the amount of content it contains, the speeds will vary because the transition is still going to continue until it reaches the max width (event thought you won't see it): [JS Fiddle - max-width-transition](http://jsfiddle.net/y5cwLLud/2/)

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 0;
    transition: max-width 0.25s linear;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a:hover span {
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Good to know that `transition` doesn't work with `auto`. How do I fix the vertical alignment of text though?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing about transiton, as it is answered you can also add following tags to css for text alignment:
    `vertical-align: bottom;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;`

Comment: @Sourabh I'm not sure what you are expecting/needing with the line-height?

Comment: I'm using line-height to vertically center the text and it looks something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y5cwLLud/3/ The bottom of `o` is not at same level as bottom of `l`

Comment: Set all to `inherit` so that these text attributes can be inherited from parent tag.

Comment: That ... was simple. I guess I overdid my css. Now I feel silly. Thanks @faith and dwreck08

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, don't have comment yet...dwreck08's answer is correct.) Fix the height with vertical-align top. Also, there was a slight gap in the underline, so you have to add it to the span and then a small negative margin on the sides:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0.25s linear;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}

a:hover span {
    width: 55px;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try this

 @font-face {
      font-family: 'Bree Serif';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Bree Serif'), local('BreeSerif-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/breeserif/v5/0daoUMW28nkWOnFz2G4AAgsYbbCjybiHxArTLjt7FRU.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
    }
    /* latin */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Bree Serif';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local('Bree Serif'), local('BreeSerif-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/breeserif/v5/LQ7WLTaITDg4OSRuOZCpswzyDMXhdD8sAj6OAJTFsBI.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        height: 200px;
        background: #aaa;
    }
    a {
        font-size: 100px;
        line-height: 200px;
        font-family: "Bree Serif";
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: underline;
        transition: linear all 1s;
        -webkit-transition: linear all 1s;
        -moz-transition: linear all 1s;
    }
    span {
        display: none;
        transition: width 0.25s linear;
        overflow-x: hidden;

    }
    a:hover {
        color: red;
    }

    a:hover span {
        width: auto;
        display: inline;
    }
```